# Doctrine2 Merge() Fails with Composite Indexes | Doctrine2 Bug?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I merge the following detached **UserAnswer** object that uses composite indexes, the merge fails if and only if I have an index with *both* a foreign key/mapped entity *and* a non-foreign key/mapped entity in the object. If the composite index includes only foreign keys or only non-foreign keys, the merge works.

I'm thinking this is a Doctrine2 bug. If not, what am I doing wrong?

Doctrine2 Version: 2.3.4

The controller code below saves a **UserAnswer** object type, which is described in the following code block:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$userAnswer = new UserAnswer();
$userAnswer->setUser($this->getUser());
$userAnswer->setAnswerType(1);
$userAnswer->setQuestion($entityManager->getReference('AcmeBundle:Question',1));

$entityManager->detach($userAnswer);
$entityManager->merge($userAnswer);
try {
    $entityManager->flush();
} catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {
...
```

**UserAnswer** Object:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="userAnswers")
 */
class UserAnswer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question")
     */
    protected $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="answer_type", type="integer")
     */
    protected $answer_type;
...
```

Here's the error I receive:

> The identifier answer_type is missing for a query of
>   AcmeBundle\Entity\UserAnswer
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - ORMException
>
> Stack Trace
>
> in
>   /vagrant/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/ORMException.php
>   at line 160   -
>
> ```
> public static function missingIdentifierField($className, $fieldName)
> {
>     return new self("The identifier $fieldName is missing for a query of " . $className);
> }
>
> public static function overwriteInternalDQLFunctionNotAllowed($functionName)
> ```
>
> at ORMException::missingIdentifierField ('Acme\Entity\UserAnswer','answer_type')  in /vagrant/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php at line 380   +
>
> at EntityManager ->find('Acme\Entity\UserAnswer', array('user' => '1','question' => '1'))  in /vagrant/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 1787   +
>
> at UnitOfWork ->doMerge (object(UserAnswer), array('0000000025cf9503000000006ed40a0a' => object(UserAnswer)))  in /vagrant/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 1701   +
>
> at UnitOfWork ->merge (object(UserAnswer))  in /vagrant/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php at line 638   +
>
> at EntityManager ->merge (object(UserAnswer))  in /vagrant/Symfony/src/Acme/Controller/UserAnswerController.php at line 23   +
>
> at UserAnswerController ->postAction () at call_user_func_array (array(object(UserAnswerController), 'postAction'), array())  in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2815   +
>
> at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')  in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2789   +
>
> at HttpKernel->handle (object(Request), '1', true)  in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2918   +
>
> at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)  in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2220   +
>
> at Kernel->handle (object(Request))  in /vagrant/Symfony/web/app_dev.php at line 31   +

This **UserAnswer** does *not* produce an error with the above controller code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="userAnswers")
 */
class UserAnswer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question")
     */
    protected $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="answer_type", type="integer")
     */
    protected $answer_type;
...
```

Nor does this one:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="userAnswers")
 */
class UserAnswer extends ApiObject
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="userid", type="integer")
     */
    protected $userid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="question_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $question_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="answer_type", type="integer")
     */
    protected $answer_type;
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ***was*** a Doctrine2 bug and fixed in Doctrine version 2.4.2, which as of this writing hasn't been released. (See http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2645.)

However, the fix is ***very*** easy to implement: https://github.com/Exeu/doctrine2/commit/edab2b6a9670dda3127f457205c7720611d6a6c9

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may be related to a known Doctrine Issue and fixed in Version 2.3.4:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2645